# Codeigniter active record find available dates for rental items

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am creating a site where users can rent items. I have 2 tables. Rentals and Inventory. The inventory table just has all the details about the product and the rentals table has the inventory id and a start date / end date for booking purposes. So if a client books an item i need to check if his dates are available using active record in codeigniter. Any ideas on how I could accomplish this...

Here is my rentals table...

```
id | customerId | productsId | periodStart (dateTime) | periodEnd (dateTime) | status
```

My user chooses his start date from a datepicker in the dateTime format (Y-m-d).

The website adds a certain amount of days to the start date to formulate an end date. So what I end up with is the customers desired date range as this:

```
$startTime = $_POST['date'];
$endTime = strtotime('+'.$periodLength.'day', $startTime);
```

how can I find out if that date range is available in the rentals table i've described above. I'm not familiar with joins, but I feel they may be necessary here.

I have tried a few things but none of it has worked. Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like that

```
    $this->db->where('start_date >=', $startTime );
    $this->db->where('end_date <=', $endTime);
    $count= $this->db->count_all_results('rentals');
    if($count > something)   //your business logic here
        return true;
    else 
        return false
```

no joins is needed if i get you right
also you can add other where clauses like id or whatever

Answer (score 0):

instead of $ startTime = $ _POST ['date']; but $ startTime = $ this-> imput-> post ('date');

add $this->load->helper('form'); early method